# Fluentd gives the error: Log file is not writable, when starting the server

Tags: fluentd

Here's my td-agent.conf file

```
<source>
 @type http  
 port 8888
</source>

<match whatever.access>
 @type file
 path /var/log/what.txt
</match>
```

But when I try to start the server using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/td-agent start
```

it gives the following error:

> '2016-02-01 10:45:49 +0530 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:359:rescue in >main_process: config error file="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf" error="out_file: >`/var/log/what.txt.20160201_0.log` is not writable"

Can someone explain what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you installed `td-agent v2`, it creates its own user and group called `td-agent`. I believe that when you run the `td-agent` service, it switches to this user and hence it expects the directory to have write permissions for this user. I faced the same issue and did something like: (Use `sudo` if needed for below commands.)

```
mkdir /logs
chown td-agent:td-agent /logs
```

and update your section to:

```
<match whatever.access>
  @type file
  path /logs/what.txt
</match>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think when you try to start td-agent, you do not have permission to access `/var/log/`, using `ls -l` to check its permission mode and change it with `chmod`.
I got the same problem, after change directory's access permission, td-agent can be started.