# Error in the dry run of a freshly installed td-agent (file not writable... or existing)

Tags: file-permissions, fluentd, strace

**The problem:**

`td-agent --dry-run` gives the following error containing output:

```
$ td-agent --dry-run
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: reading config file path="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf"
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: starting fluentd-0.12.35 as dry run mode
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluent-mixin-config-placeholders' version '0.4.0'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluent-mixin-plaintextformatter' version '0.2.6'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kafka' version '0.5.5'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-mongo' version '0.8.0'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '1.5.5'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '0.8.2'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-scribe' version '0.10.14'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td' version '0.10.29'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td-monitoring' version '0.2.2'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '0.4.2'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '0.12.35'
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [info]: adding match pattern="td.*.*" type="tdlog"
2017-08-01 15:31:49 +0200 [error]: dry run failed: out_file: `/var/log/td-agent/failed_records.20170801_0.log` is not writable
```

The error: `/var/log/td-agent/failed_records.20170801_0.log` is not writable

**The question:**

What could cause this error, and what can I try to resolve it? Note (below) that the file does not exist, and the directory is writable.

*Side-remark:* I will really appreciate any links to debugging features of `td-agent`. (Adding `DAEMON_ARGS=-vv` to `/etc/default/td-agent` and restarting the daemon, made no difference to the output.)

**The setup and what I tried:**

I installed td-agent on Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty zapus), using the official documentation: 
https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/install-by-deb#step-0-before-installation

I followed all the pre-installation steps: 
https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/install-by-deb

I installed td-agent with the instructions for Xenial, since Zesty was not on the list. So I did:

```
$ curl -L https://toolbelt.treasuredata.com/sh/install-ubuntu-xenial-td-agent2.sh | sh
```

The status seems fine:

```
$ /etc/init.d/td-agent status
● td-agent.service - LSB: data collector for Treasure Data
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/td-agent; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-08-01 11:12:30 CEST; 2min 36s ago
    Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 6386 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/td-agent start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Tasks: 9 (limit: 4915)
  Memory: 82.2M
     CPU: 393ms
  CGroup: /system.slice/td-agent.service
          ├─6419 /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ruby /usr/sbin/td-agent --log /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.…id
          └─6422 /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ruby /usr/sbin/td-agent --log /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.…id

Aug 01 11:12:29 foo.bar systemd[1]: Starting LSB: data collector for Treasure Data...
Aug 01 11:12:30 foo.bar td-agent[6386]: Starting td-agent:  * td-agent
Aug 01 11:12:30 foo.bar systemd[1]: Started LSB: data collector for Treasure Data.
```

The file does not exist, the directory is writable, and I am in the group `td-agent`, so I don't think this is related to [Fluentd gives the error: Log file is not writable, when starting the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123483/fluentd-gives-the-error-log-file-is-not-writable-when-starting-the-server?rq=1).

```
$ ls -la /var/log/td-agent
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  3 td-agent td-agent  4096 Aug  1 11:12 .
drwxrwxr-x 17 root     syslog    4096 Aug  1 14:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 td-agent td-agent  4096 Aug  1 11:12 buffer
-rw-r--r--  1 td-agent td-agent 17034 Aug  1 14:21 td-agent.log


$ groups foo
foo : foo adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker td-agent
```

The relevant snippet of strace:

```
[pid  8484] open("/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/zlib.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  8484] open("/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 7
[pid  8484] fcntl(7, F_GETFD)           = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
[pid  8484] fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=256704, ...}) = 0
[pid  8484] fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=256704, ...}) = 0
[pid  8484] close(7)                    = 0
[pid  8484] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2335, ...}) = 0
[pid  8484] stat("/var/log/td-agent/failed_records.20170802_0.log",  0x7ffe01bfc4f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  8484] stat("/var/log/td-agent/failed_records.20170802_0.log", 0x7ffe01bfc4f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  8484] stat("/var/log/td-agent/failed_records.20170802_0.log", 0x7ffe01bfc4f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  8484] stat("/var/log/td-agent", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid  8484] stat("/var/log/td-agent", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid  8484] stat("/var/log/td-agent", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
[pid  8484] geteuid()                   = 1000
[pid  8484] getegid()                   = 1000
[pid  8484] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid  8484] getgid()                    = 1000
[pid  8484] access("/var/log/td-agent", W_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid  8484] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2335, ...}) = 0
[pid  8484] write(1, "\33[1;35m2017-08-02 10:12:51 +0200"...,    1402017-08-02 10:12:51 +0200 [error]: dry run failed: out_file: `/var/log/td-  agent/failed_records.20170802_0.log` is not writable) = 140
```

---- (another) Edit:

Ok, so the group does not have write permission, and (most importantly) td-agent does not become user td-agent (even if run it as root - it stays root). Is this a bug or a feature of td-agent?